# Webpack is generating budles for all the entrypoints combined in one bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

These are the entry points in my webpack config

```
const allEntries = {
  main: ['./src/client.js', './src/client.scss'],
  mobile: ['./src/mobileClient.js', './src/mobileClient.scss'],
  homeloan: ['./src/app/pages/homeloan/index.js'],
  eoiWidget: './src/app/pages/eoi/index.js',
  hlWidget: ['./src/app/pages/homeloan/hlWidget/index.js'],
  login: './src/app/components/common/desktop/LoginRegisterWidget/loginBundle.js',
  gdprWidget: './src/app/components/gdpr/gdprIndex',
  mobileEoiWrapper: './src/app/components/EOI/MobileEOI/Containers/MobileEoiPhp.js',
  contactFormWrapper: './src/app/components/EOI/ContactFormPhp.js',
  xidRevampAppWebViewLayers: ["./src/app/pages/xid/projectDetailV2/components/mobile/moreDetailLayers/index.js"],
  smartAppBanner: './src/app/components/common/mobile/SmartAppBanner/SmartAppBannerPHPWrapper.js',
  srpapp: ['./src/app/pages/searchPg/srpMicrositeApp/client.js', './src/app/pages/searchPg/srpMicrositeApp/client.scss'],
};
```

It is generating bundles for all the entry points and async imported components separately for e.g.

```
const AsyncPhoton = asyncComponent(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Photon" */'../../../components/common/shared/PhotonPD/index'));

"AsyncPhoton~31ecd969": {
    "css": "universalapp/css/AsyncPhoton~31ecd969.38901334dc51d15a1cef.css",
    "js": "universalapp/js/AsyncPhoton~31ecd969Bundle.7228863223bbca46d9df.js"
  },
```

but it is also generating one bundle which is having combined name of all the entry points and it is getting imported on main page load

```
ContactFormWrapper~eoiWidget~gdprWidget~hlWidget~login~mobile~mobileEoiWrapper~smartAppBanner~srpapp~b0f61cc4.32333713d7427fcbf0ba: {
    "css": "universalapp/css/ContactFormWrapper~eoiWidget~gdprWidget~hlWidget~login~mobile~mobileEoiWrapper~smartAppBanner~srpapp~b0f61cc4.32333713d7427fcbf0ba",
    "js": "universalapp/js/ContactFormWrapper~eoiWidget~gdprWidget~hlWidget~login~mobile~mobileEoiWrapper~smartAppBanner~srpapp~b0f61cc4.32333713d7427fcbf0ba"
}
```

I tried giving **webpackChunkName** inline coment to all the async import components but problemn stil persist. Can you help me in this.